# Convergence of a sequence of polynomials

Tags: calculus, analysis, polynomials

Let $\{p_n(\cdot)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of polynomials on $[0,1]$, e.g., $p_n(x) = \sum_{i=3}^{d_n} p_{i,n} x^i$, where $d_n$ is the maximal degree which is increasing (at most linearly) in $n$, and $p_{i,n}$ are non-negative coefficients such that $\sum_{i=3}^{d_n} p_{i,n} = 1$. For each $n$ further let $p_n(0)=0$ and $p_n(1)=1$, and assume that $\sum_{i=3}^{d_n} i p_{i,n}$ diverge to $+\infty$ as $n \to +\infty$. The second-order derivative of $p_n(\cdot)$ is given by
\begin{equation}
p^{''} _n (x) = \sum_{i=3}^{d_n} i(i-1) p_{i,n} x^{i-2}.
\end{equation}
Take for example $d_n = n$ and $p_{n, n} = 1$ so that $p_n(x)=x^{n}$. Then $p^{''} _n (x) = n(n-1)x^{n-2}$. For fixed $ 0 < x < 1$, this converges to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Does it hold in general that, for fixed $0 < x < 1$, the sequence of second-order derivatives $\{p_n ^{''}(x)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded from above by a finite constant?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you allow your constant to depend on $x$, the answer is yes.  Indeed, fix $x \in (0,1)$ and let
$$C_x = \sup_{i \ge 3} i(i-1)x^{i-2}$$
(which must be finite, since $\lim_{i \to \infty} i(i-1)x^{i-2} = 0$).  Then,
$$\sum_{i=3}^{d_n} i(i-1)p_{i,n}x^{i-2} \leq \sum_{i=3}^{d_n} C_x p_{i,n} = C_x.$$

On the other hand, $C_x \to \infty$ as $x \to 1$ (can you see why?), so we cannot get a uniform bound for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Perhaps it is because $C_1=\infty$ and $C_x$ should be increasing in $x$?

Comment: @user592237 That suggests the limit should be infinite, but it isn't a proof without an argument that $\lim_{x \to 1^-} C_x = C_1$.  Instead, I would argue that $C_{x_i} \ge \frac{i(i-1)}{2}$ for $x_i = 2^{-\frac{1}{i-2}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I see your point. So on the other hand, can we say that, if $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of numbers such that $0 < x_n < 1$ for every $n$, then the condition $\limsup_{n \to \infty} p^{''} _n (x_n) < \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n ^{''} (1) = \infty$ must imply that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n < 1$?

Comment: @user592237 Yes, that's right.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to prove it? I am not sure how to address limits when both the function $p_n ^{''}$ and its argument $x_n$ depend on $n$. Thanks so much.

Comment: @user592237 Sorry, I actually misunderstood your question.  In general, we don't have the result about the supremum of the $x_n$'s: just take $p_n$ to be a constant sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But there are still conditions $\lim_{n \to \infty} p^{''} _n (1) = \infty$ so that $\{p_n(\cdot)\}$ is not a constant polynomial. If we take e.g., $p_n(x) = x^n$ so that $p^{''} _n (1) = n (n-1)$ which goes to $\infty$. If $\limsup_{n \to \infty} n (n-1) (x_n) ^{n-2} < \infty$, then does the sequence of numbers $\{x_n\}$ hold that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n < 1$, or could it still goes to 1?